# logical problem in an android app

Tags: android, logic

hi i would like to know solution for such a problem..... i have an xml file containing users data of around 1000 users listed out in alphabetical order. The xml file use to be as follow

```
<usersdata>
    <user>
         <id>1</id>
         <firstname>A</firstname>
         <middlename>AA</middlename>
         ......
         ......
    </user>
    <user>
         <id>2</id>
         <firstname>B</firstname>
          <middlename>BB</middlename>
           ......
           ......
    </user>
    ........
    ........
</usersdata>
```

Now from the above xml file i am parsing all the tags and storing them in an array list for each tag. I am listing out the Firstname in a listview, by array list of first name. When the any of the list is clicked, it opens up a new activity where the all other details of the selected name is been shown.

For example if third name in the list is clicked, by using its `position(example 3)`, in the next activity i am listing out the third values stored in all the array lists i am using. This is what currently i am doing.

Now the problem is i have a edit box above the list view, named as a search box. If the letter `S` is typed in it, then all the names starting with S gets listed first. Opening the next activity by clicking the list now gets some wrong data, how to avoid this.

Please give me a suggestion....

For example if the first name `C` is clicked, it will be listed at position 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried out by setting some flag and by using an example code in developers site. And i am able to list out the data's but this idea does not full fill my apps requirement in the next activity. So i removed the search part in my app.

Sorry for posting such a question here......

Answer (score 1):

There is a quick and dirty hack: you can store user id in the invisible field, retrieve it on click and use it as an argument for the second activity. I'm afraid I can't come up with better suggestions without seeing the code.